# OrangePi 5 disconnecting from internet-less ethernet

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, raspberrypi

We just purchased an OrangePi 5 and tried to run both the OrangePi Bullseye OS and Ubuntu Focal yet we face the same issue in both. The ethernet (eth0) keeps disconnecting from our Doodle Radio (which is an RF mesh communication device) every few minutes.

When we plug in an ethernet from the Wi-Fi router we don't have the issue. We have multiple regular laptops running windows and RaspberryPis running raspbian and have never seen this issue when interacting with the radios.

Any thoughts on what it could be? My current suspicion is that the ethernet driver doesn't like that the ethernet from the radio doesn't have internet connection as it's meant to be a local closed off network.

Thanks!

Comment: If multiple OS have same issue that usually means hardware.

Comment: Having no internet connection is no reason to disconnect. Do a `grep -i dhcp /var/log/syslog` and see if you can figure out what goes wrong. One thing that comes to mind is setting a fixed IP address that is unavailable.

Comment: Read the logs, `sudo journalctl -xe -p err`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, when setting the static IP you have to change the "method" tab to "Manual" and cannot leave it as "DHCP" which was the default.